# let alone he or let alone him

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-case

Should I say 'he' or 'him' in the following situation?

> Even I am not going, let alone he.
>
> Even I am not going, let alone him.

Comment: The sentence does not make much sense.  Did you mean to say, "I'm not even going, let alone *with* him"?

Answer (score 5):

The idiom "X let alone Y" means to consider Y in contrast to X, making Y the object of the verb "let," which puts Y in the **objective case**.  Thus:

> I am not going, let alone **him**.

Comment: By the way, I think your sentence is still wrong. There's no need for a comma there, and you have to include a 'to', so 'I'm not even going to let him alone' (him before is better)

Comment: @JuanRocamonde "Let him alone" is a different idiom from "let alone him."  The former means to leave him in peace, i.e., not to bother him.  The latter means as I explained in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I apologise.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde No need to apologize.  English idioms are tricky, and these are very close, just two words swapped.  As long as you're clear.  I guarantee that your English is better than my Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Typical use of "let alone" is: The baby can't even sit up yet, let alone walk.

In your case I would say: I'm not going, nor is he.